# Naming new access table coded via vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

Hey I've been looking at previous posts in regards to naming created tables in vb.net, and although I'm using the same code apparently my syntax isn't correct for creating new tables with a name from a textbox. What do you thinK?

```
 dbprovider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
        dbsource = "Data Source = FULL YUGIOH ACCESS DATABASE.accdb;"
        conn.ConnectionString = dbprovider & dbsource
        Dim connectionString As String = dbprovider & dbsource
        Using con As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
            con.Open()
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand()
                cmd.Connection = con
                cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE " & TextBox4.Text & "(ID COUNTER, [name] STRING)"
                Try
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    MsgBox("Table created.")
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                End Try
            End Using
            con.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Comment: You would start to use parameters in your queries, else it will be vulnerable to SQL injection attack

Comment: Your `CommandText` is correct, but you probably need the _full path_ for `dbsource`.

Comment: [SQL CREATE TABLE Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp).

Comment: You need a space after the table name, `" (ID Counter, ...` also you should wrap the user input with [ ] because if the user enters a space or a few other characters the command will fail.

Comment: Jimi sorry but your code isn't working, and Charles I added a space before (ID Counter) and I still get a syntax error. Would you have any other ideas?